# When can I ask several questions in a row, without waiting?

Tags: support, questions, rate-limiting

When I have tried to ask several questions in a row, a message indicates that I have to wait for 20 minutes before posting my next question. Sometimes I want to ask more questions.

Why is that, and when is that limitation removed?

Comment: How much time are you even spending on writing these questions up properly?

Comment: How many questions do you have, and do they really need to come that fast and furious? Spend more time writing the question, *formatting* it, making sure the grammar/spelling/capitalization/punctuation is correct, and you'll find that the rate limiter won't be an issue anymore.

Comment: @Mirror51: FWIW... I've spent a little bit of time looking through your questions just now. While they're not terrible, you could really stand to spent a little bit of time proof-reading them after posting. Good way to kill some time while you're waiting to post your next question...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why is that

[Some jackass abused the site and ruined it for everyone else.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/new-question-answer-rate-limits/)

> and when is that limitation removed

When you get at least 100 reputation points. So, ask a few *good* questions, and when they get up-voted you'll be able to ask more *good* questions.

Comment: Thanks buddy that was what i needed to know

Comment: Or just join SU or SF and link your accounts. That gets you over the limit I think.

Comment: Yacoby: Nope, you have to be at least 200 rep on one site to get the bonus on the others. By then you're already over the hump.